# PostRowsInGroups is giving badRequest from Json object

Tags: json, post, dataset, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have the following code to create a JSON object and then post this to a streaming data set in powerBI. With the code, I have so far I seem to be finding the dataset and table just fine but I am getting a bad request on my json object. Is there something simple I'm missing in the code below that is preventing this from working?

```
using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
{
    var payload = new testValues
    {
        value1 = "test",
        value2 = counter,
        value3 = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    string stringPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
    StringContent postContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    ODataResponseListDataset datasets = client.Datasets.GetDatasetsInGroup(GroupId);
    client.Datasets.PostRowsInGroup(GroupId, datasets.Value.LastOrDefault().Id, "RealTimeData", postContent);
    counter++;
    return;
}
```

and below is the testValues class just in case that can also shed some light on my issue here:

```
public class testValues
{
    [JsonProperty("value1")]
    public string value1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value2")]
    public int value2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value3")]
    public DateTime value3 { get; set; }
}
```